# MySQL ERROR 1146 (42S02) Table 'securities_master.exchange' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm running MySQL 5.7.20 on a Mac, which I installed with Homebrew. I created a database and in that database created a table as per the following steps:

1. CREATE DATABASE securities_master;
2. USE securities_master;
3. CREATE USER ’sec_user’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ’password’;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON securities_master.* TO ’sec_user’@’localhost’;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4. CREATE TABLE ‘exchange‘ (
   ‘id‘ int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ‘abbrev‘ varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   ‘name‘ varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   ‘city‘ varchar(255) NULL,
   ‘country‘ varchar(255) NULL,
   ‘currency‘ varchar(64) NULL,
   ‘timezone_offset‘ time NULL,
   ‘created_date‘ datetime NOT NULL,
   ‘last_updated_date‘ datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (‘id‘)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
5. SELECT * FROM exchange;

The last statement generates the following error message:

'ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'securities_master.exchange' doesn't exist'

But if I run SHOW TABLES the 'exchange' does exist. May someone help me please I'm a newbie to MySQL.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but in `CREATE TABLE ‘exchange‘` I see strange looking single curly quotes arouns the table name.

Comment: Are you using CLI/commands to cerate DB and tables?

Comment: Can you please first Insert 1 record in table then try : SELECT * FROM exchange;

Comment: It's true that a table called ‘exchange‘ is created but since the strange looking quote that @Tim Biegeleisen refers to is not the recognised escape character (backtick) used for defining tables and columns then you will forever have to refer to the table and its columns using the quote you created it with. Best drop the table and recreate using backtick.

Comment: Thanks Tim removing the strange looking curly quotes has fixed the problem.